# SQL function in presto CROSS JOIN statement

Tags: sql, presto, cross-join

Trying to understand the presto CROSS JOIN and UNNEST statements from the [docs here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html), there is a code snippet that I don't understand:

```
SELECT student, score
FROM tests
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(scores) AS t (score);
```

I don't understand the lowercase t -- is it a function? What does it do? In my own tables, the query stops working when I remove the t and the parentheses, but I can't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

`t` is an alias, not a function. `UNNEST(scores) AS t` provides a virtual table, aliased `t`.

Comment: Thanks for that, I wasn't familiar with the concept of aliases. That said, what does the `(score)` bit do?

Comment: It cross joins the tables `tests` and `t` (unnested scores) based on `score` column value.